# How to get a specific word from a text file in c++?

Tags: c++, console

I am trying to get a specific word from a .txt file content. Let say, I have a .txt file:

**cottage.txt**

```
1 [1] Cottage1 1000 01-10-2019 Free
2 [2] vottage2 2000 01-20-2019 Free
```

I want to get the word 1000 when I select the line with an ID of (1) or get the word 2000 with an ID of (2) depending on the user input.

**My Code:** - I know this is incomplete but I just to show what I have tried so far.

```
string GetWord(string filename)
{
    string word;
    string selectline;

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(filename);
    cout << "Select which line to get a word from: "; //select line
    cin >> selectline;

    //some code here......

    temp.close();
    fin.close();

    return word;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format of every line in the text file is same, then you can try this code-

```
string GetWord(string filename)
{
    string word, line;
    int selectline;

    ifstream fin(filename.c_str());

    cout << "Select which line to get a word from: "; //select line
    cin >> selectline;

    int i = 1;
    while (getline(fin, line))
    {
        if(i == selectline){
            istringstream ss(line);
            for (int j=0; j<4; j++){
                ss >> word;
            }
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return word;
}
```

Please let me know if you still have the problem :)

Comment: Where does the "ss" come from?

Comment: its a variable name of istringstream class type which is declared inside the if condition. It's taking each line as a stream in ss variable.

Comment: it says, incomplete type is not allowed.

Comment: Can you please check if you have included the necessary header file for istringstream? you can check by adding this, #include <sstream>